# Insert Div into the DOM and add attributes in Angular using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Would there be any reason the following code would not insert a DIV into the DOM and add the ID attribute? For some reason it is not working:

```
createDivs() {
    const target = document.querySelector(".navbar");
    const createDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    createDiv.setAttribute("id", "result-div");
    createDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Yes</p>";
    createDiv.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", target);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createDivs();
  }
```

Comment: I think `document.createElement("DIV");` should be `document.createElement("div");`... I've never seen someone use capital letters in `document.createElement("tag-string");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called `insertAdjacentElement` on the new element instead of on the sibling element... [check the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)
Instead of using

```
createDiv.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", target);
```

you should use

```
target.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", createDiv);
```

Comment: Thats right. That was it. Target should be first.